# picasawebservice java authentication access denied

Tags: google-oauth, picasa

My previously working picasawebservice code failed when Google switched to the OAuth 2 authentication.

I have modified the code to use a Goodle credential for which I needed to set up a Service Account.

Although no errors are returned when I add the credential to the PicasawebService object I cannot add any photos to my album.

I have obtained a list of albums using the url https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/xxx?kind=album but it only returns the public Profile Album, not the other albums on the account, also when I use the album id returned by the feed I get an "Access forbidden" error when I try to insert a photo. (xxx - I have used both the user id and the email address for the account and get the same result in each case).

I have been able to establish the alubum ids for the private albums on the account but using these also failed when attempting an insert.

The code is

```
      String emailAddress = "-- the email address from the Google Developers console for the credential --";
      JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
      GoogleCredential credential = null;
      try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://picasaweb.google.com/data","http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api"};
        final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);

        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("-- the p12 key file --"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .build();
      } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        logger.error("processUpload: Error getting Google credential " + accountBean.getZuzzAccountId() + " - " + accountBean.getAccountTitle() + " - " + ex.toString());
        uploadMessage = "Error getting a connection to the photo store - please see the administratior";
        return;
      }    

      credential.refreshToken();
      String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();

      PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("Zuzz-ZuzzClub-1.2");
      myService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

      URL albumPostUrl = null;
      try {
        albumPostUrl = new URL("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/--  my user id --/albumid/-- album id returned from feed --");
      } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        logger.error("processUpload: Error getting album post url for account " + accountBean.getZuzzAccountId() + " - " + accountBean.getAccountTitle() + " - " + ex.toString());
        uploadMessage = "Error getting a connection to the photo store - please see the administratior";
        return;
      }

      PhotoEntry myPhoto = new PhotoEntry();
      myPhoto.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(fileName));
      myPhoto.setDescription(new PlainTextConstruct(months.get(Integer.valueOf(editionMonth).intValue()) + " " + editionYear));
      myPhoto.setClient("ZuzzClub");

      MediaStreamSource myMedia = null;
      myMedia = new MediaStreamSource(imageInStream,"image/jpeg");
      if (myMedia == null) {
        logger.error("processUpload: Error generating the thumbnail photo - null media source for account " + accountBean.getZuzzAccountId() + " - " + accountBean.getAccountTitle());
        uploadMessage = "Error generating the thumbnail photo - please see the administratior";
        return;
      }
      myPhoto.setMediaSource(myMedia);

      thumbNailUrl = null;
      try {
        PhotoEntry returnedPhoto = myService.insert(albumPostUrl, myPhoto);
        ArrayList<MediaContent> mediaContent = (ArrayList<MediaContent>) returnedPhoto.getMediaContents();
        thumbNailUrl = mediaContent.get(0).getUrl();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("processUpload: Error adding photo to Photo store for account " + accountBean.getZuzzAccountId() + " - " + accountBean.getAccountTitle() + " - " + ex.toString());
        uploadMessage = "Error generating the thumbnail photo - please see the administratior";
        return;
      } catch (ServiceException ex) {
        logger.error("processUpload: Error adding photo to Photo store for account " + accountBean.getZuzzAccountId() + " - " + accountBean.getAccountTitle() + " - " + ex.toString());
        uploadMessage = "Error generating the thumbnail photo - please see the administratior";
        return;
      } finally {
        imageInStream.close();
      }
```

The problem appears to be that the authentication has not granted permission to perform the insert, however the service account is set to "Can edit" in the Google Developers Console.

Is there a way of finding out what permissions the service has after the credential has been applied?

Has anyone managed to add photos to a Picasa album after the authentication change?

Comment: I don't think that you can use a service account with Picasa, you are going to have to use oauth2.   Service accounts need to be pre authorized you cant give another user access to your Picasa directory can you?

Comment: I thought the Service Account was part of the oauth2 mechanism and was the option to use if you did not want the user to have to enter their authority each time you wanted to connect to the Picasa account. Do you have some sample code that works?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help with java and there aren't a lot of working examples for the old gdata APIs because most of them have been shut down.

Comment: I have made some progress but still not got a full solution. The post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picasa-data-api/i3Lz6gXYtwc describes the procedure to get an access token for a web application. Using this procedure and the code changed to create a new Credential with the access token, the account can be accessed, a list of albums retrieved and a new photo added to an album, however even though the refreshToken method is used on the credential, this only works until the access token expires after about an hour

Comment: every hour you will have to refresh it.

Comment: I'm very surprised, this is not a workable solution. Have Google really killed the application interface to Picasa?

Comment: They haven't it's called Oauth2 this is how you access Google apis

Comment: I am aware that they are using OAuth2, what I am looking for is an option where I can use the OAuth2 mechanism without the user having to authenticate via the browser every time I want to add something to the Picasa album. I have used the OAuth2.0 Playground to get the access and refresh codes. The access code expires but the refresh code does not, so I am looking for a way to refresh the access code programatically without the user having to interact

Comment: Great question. Have you solved this now ?

Comment: No, I tried every solution that I could find and nothing worked, it looks like the only way you can add photos is to get the user to authorise each connection through a Google panel which is not a satisfactory solution - after spending a lot of frustrating time on this, I have moved away from Google.